# How to handle click window event in good way using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a window that can be opened by clicking a button using javascript. The window cannot be closed by clicking on the inside of the window, and the window can only be closed by clicking on the outside of the window. At present, I always grab e.target.className to judge whether the clicked element should close the window, but if there are hundreds of elements in a window, this method does not seem to be a good way. I would like to ask if there is a formal What's a good way to handle this need?

```js
$('.click').on('click',function(e){
   $('.dialog').toggle()
  $(document).on('click',function(e){
    if(e.target.className == 'confirm' || e.target.className == 'item' || e.target.className == 'text' || e.target.className == 'dialog_wrap' || e.target.className == 'dialog' || e.target.className == 'head' || e.target.className == 'title'){
      $('.dialog').css('display','inline-block');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.click {
  position: relative;
}
.click .dialog {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.click .dialog li {
  text-align: left;
}
.click .dialog .confirm {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">click

<div class="dialog">
  <header class="head">
    <h1 class="title">my is title</h1>
  </header>
   <ul class='dialog_wrap'>
     <li class='item'>
       <p class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</p>
       <span class='time'>2022-12-23</span>
     </li>
      <li class='item'>
       <p class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</p>
       <span class='time'>2022-12-23</span>
     </li>
      <li class='item'>
       <p class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</p>
       <span class='time'>2022-12-23</span>
     </li>
      <li class='item'>
       <p class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</p>
       <span class='time'>2022-12-23</span>
     </li>
      <input type="button" value="confirm" class="confirm">
   </ul>
</div>
</button>
```

Comment: _"What's a good way to handle this need?"_ - Adding a new/additional `click` handler on the `document` on every click of an `.click` element is definitely not the correct way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Find whether the click was inside the `.dialog` with [`.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest). If it returns a `.dialog` element, the click was inside, so do nothing; otherwise, the click was outside or on the button, so you can close the dialog.

Also, you almost certainly don't want to add another click listener to the document every time `.click` is clicked; better to only add the listener once.

```js
const dialog = $('.dialog');
$('.click').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.closest('.dialog')) {
    dialog.toggle();
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  dialog.hide();
});
```

```css
.click {
  position: relative;
}

.click .dialog {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.click .dialog li {
  text-align: left;
}

.click .dialog .confirm {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">click

<div class="dialog">
  <header class="head">
    <h1 class="title">my is title</h1>
  </header>
   <ul class='dialog_wrap'>
     <li class='item'>
       <p class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</p>
       <span class='time'>2022-12-23</span>
     </li>
      <li class='item'>
       <p class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</p>
       <span class='time'>2022-12-23</span>
     </li>
      <li class='item'>
       <p class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</p>
       <span class='time'>2022-12-23</span>
     </li>
      <li class='item'>
       <p class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur</p>
       <span class='time'>2022-12-23</span>
     </li>
      <input type="button" value="confirm" class="confirm">
   </ul>
</div>
</button>
```

Comment: But you are checking for click element on the button to check. ".click" is the button to show the modal

Comment: This seems to be a good way, because I am still a beginner in programming, let me study your logic, thank you

Comment: @bugwheels94 Yes, the first handler will handle if the click is on or inside the button. In the case of the click being on the `.dialog`, it'll do nothing. If it's on the button itself, it'll toggle (either show or hide). Otherwise, if the click is outside the button, the dialog will be hidden.

Comment: ohh I just saw ".click" is parent of modal. OP got some weird HTML to be exact. Caught me offgaurd. @AWEI please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button whether it is allowed or not to to put so many interactive elements inside button

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand you, because I am a novice in programming, maybe my writing is not very good~ I put so much HTML in the button because I hope to use position: relative; in the button and then set the position in the HTML (window) : absolute; Make it positioned above. In this way, the button can be clicked so that the window can be fixed and appear under the button, so that the position will not run away. But I should change the way to avoid multiple HTML inside the button.

Comment: @AWEI Yes, you should definitely restructure things if you can, the current approach is pretty weird. Instead, have a separate element next to the button in the HTML that gets styled to appear where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a body id when the click starts, and you can close the form when you click anywhere on the body.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).